# Live SDK - server_internal_error - message - An error occurred while retrieving the resource. Try again later

Tags: rest, authentication, onedrive, live-sdk

Currently it looks like the lice SDK returns error 500 for all request. Also the interactive SDK Microsoft provides here returns the same error:

http://isdk.dev.live.com/dev/isdk/ISDK.aspx?category=scenarioGroup_core_concepts&index=1

My application work without any changes for over 24 months. Has someone any more details or a workaround?

Update: I tried the following API calls both with the same result:

- https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=#Token#
- https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/picture?access_token=#Token#

Comment: Having the same problem :( https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token= returns "error": {
"code": "server_internal_error"
"message": "An error occurred while retrieving the resource. Try again later."
}

Comment: Looks like it's an issue on Microsoft. Thanks for the verification. Since Stackoverflow is the forum for the LiveSDK, can someone help from Microsoft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, and after a very long downtime (more than 20 hours) the Live API is up & running again.
Unfortunately, there is not even an official announcement from Microsoft.

[Up & Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbAoA.png)

Comment: Absolutely, my apps are working without errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem and all of my apps worked before for very long time.

I'm using **LiveSDK 5.6** and getting successful response for LiveAuthClient.LoginAsync with the following scopes: **"wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.contacts_photos", "wl.contacts_skydrive",
"wl.skydrive_update"**

LoginAsync returns LiveLoginResult object where:

Status = Connected

Session = {Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectSession} with AccessToken

but when app trying to call

Session (LiveConnectClient) object with GetAsync ("/me")

I'm getting the following exception

[Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectException] = {"**An error occurred while retrieving the resource. Try again later**."}
ErrorCode = "**server_internal_error**"

Comment: Yes right, looks like oauth works well but calls into the API are broken :-(

Answer (score 0):

The OneDrive service experienced a service outage on the 9th, you can see from this [3rd party site](http://downdetector.com/status/onedrive/news/19793-problems-at-onedrive-2) for an idea of the timeline.  We did not communicate this issue well to you and other developers that have come to expect excellence from OneDrive.

It is the start of a long weekend and I do not have more answers for you at this time, I'll circle back next week with better details on what to do in the future.

The Live Connect API that the LiveSDK works in conjunction with has been replaced by the [OneDrive API](https://dev.onedrive.com/), which also has [SDKs](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdks.htm) for most major platforms.  You will see major performance improvements and a larger feature set such as a modern sync API available for you with this new API if you transition to it.

Comment: Does this mean we should migrate from the Live API to the OneDrive API when we try to receive profile information for users which are logging into our applications with a Microsoft ID?

Comment: I would highly recommend it, at this time not all information is exposed, follow this issue in our GitHub to track email address availability https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/202